# Set y-axis region in react chart js

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

[image]

I have to implement the chart according to the image above.
The Y-axis area should be divided into two areas and used widely from 0 to 6, From 7 to the maximum, it should look narrow.
Please let me know how TT

https://codesandbox.io/embed/charming-ives-ddgq92?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark